# Does a screensaver still have to be installed into System32?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, screensaver

Back in my Delphi days, I wrote several screensavers - each was a single executable that was dropped into the `System32` folder, where the Windows XP Display control panel saw it and made it available. All good.

I'm now writing a significantly more complex screensaver in C# that is necessarily spread across multiple assemblies (it's using a plug-in model: merging all the assemblies into a single executable isn't an option).

Dumping all the files into `System32` doesn't seem to be very tidy - not to mention that it simply won't work on a 64-bit system.

**Is there any other way to install a screensaver on a Windows system?**

I'm willing to take a dependency on Vista/Win7 if necessary.

The only suggestion I've had made so far, is to install the bulk of the screensaver normally, under `Program Files`, and put a trigger/launcher into System32.

Comment: What's up with the vote to close? If it doesn't belong here on SO, where does it belong?

Comment: I didn't vote, but most likely it's because this is not strictly a programming question. It's more of a "how to configure a system properly/cleanly". Programming related, but not strictly programming.

Comment: I guess I can see how someone might think that. In my case, since `System32` is on the PATH and I'm using some of popular libraries (e.g. Ninject), it becomes pretty important that I don't put them into that directory, else I risk breaking other peoples applications. Sigh, I guess this is where the GAC comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32bit screensavers go into system32, while 64bit screensavers go into SysWoW64.

Comment: Useful information, thanks. But, is there any way to avoid the file pollution problem?

Comment: Not really. MS has gotten a bit better with moving things out of the \windows tree for installable stuff, but some things still have to go in there, regardless of how "dirty" it seems. Screensavers are one of those things.

Comment: @MarcB `System32` is the 64 bit directory and `SysWow64` is the 32 on bit directory on 64 bit Windows.  So 64 bit screensavers would go into the `System32` directory.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff955767.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @shf301: Leave it to MS to come up with completely back-asswards directory names. Next up, they'll finally rename the start button "shutdown" like it should've been all along.

Comment: @MarcB then you also have the fun 64/32bit Registrykey ... Wow6432Node which is where 32bit HKLM/Software goes on 64bit windows

Comment: Marc B: Leave it to incompetent developers which assume things on a system that never were guaranteed. At some point anything you do cannot change because too many idiots rely on it. You can read Raymond Chen's blog for quite many of those things :-)

Comment: @Joey: Yeah, kudos to microsoft for bending over so far for backwards compatibility, but as boo/hiss for having done so. At some point you just have to say "look, that's stone age, we're moving forwards, tough noogie".

Answer (score 5):

I found more information ...

A screensaver **does not** have to be installed into `System32` (or `SysWoW64`).

**However**, the control panel won't find it and won't list it for selection.

**Unless** it's configured as the current screensaver.

Let me explain ... the current screensaver is specified by the `SCRNSAVE.EXE` registry key found in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. The value of this key is the complete path to a `.SCR` file.

The *Display* (XP) or *Screen Saver* (Win7) control panel scans `System32` (and `SysWow64` on 64 bit systems) for `.SCR` files. It *also* scans the folder containing the current screensaver, if that's different.

So, if you set the registry key directly, the screensaver will be listed by the control panel and available for selection. But, as soon as the user selects a different screensaver, the *next* invocation of the control panel won't list the new screensaver.

Comment: Can you use a shortcut in System32 or SysWoW64 that links to a screensaver in the Program Files/ directory?

Comment: Shortcuts don't have the right file extension - it scans for `.scr` files only.

Comment: Do you have any solution as to how to install screensaver into its own dir but have it show up in the Screensaver utility? I'm writing one now and almost finished but don't have this problem solved yet.

Comment: The only reliable approach I found was to write a shim executable - a small, single file, `.scr` file that launches the actual screensaver in turn.

Comment: I believe that will work on Windows. I am writing a cross platform screensaver. I believe I already have a solution for Linux desktops so that just leaves me with Mac OS machines. I believe Mac OS uses a DLL style callback system for its screensavers. I'm wondering if I can create a launcher app the same way you suggest in Windows and have it work. Would you happen to know? Appreciate the tips!